Orthogonal complement of orthogonal complement WITHOUT mentioning closure
I am currently studying a second course in linear algebra, often exposed to infinite dimensional examples, I have came across these from the forum that those may be true:
Fix a subspace W in an inner-product space V,

$W=(W^\perp)^\perp \iff W=\overline{W}$ and $W\oplus W^\perp=V \iff W=\overline{W}$.

Though I am familiar with an introductory course in point-set topology, I need to avoid stuff about functional analysis, as I have almost never touched it.
I may have a simple counter-example to above when $W$ is not closed in $V$, like $V=\mathbb{R}^\omega$ the real sequence space, $W=\mathbb{R}^\infty$ the eventually zero sequence subspace, and $\overline{W}=V$ (please correct me if this is not a correct counter-example). But my question is, can we show that

$\tag{1} W=(W^\perp)^\perp \iff W\oplus W^\perp=V$

using purely linear algebra? I know how to prove the if part. Is the only if part also true?
I suspect the following is true and may help, but I have no idea how to prove it:

$\tag{2} W^\perp\oplus(W^\perp)^\perp=V$

I have broswed through the forum and many posts are about orthogonal complement of orthogonal complement, but most of them just stop at the criterion of $W$ being closed in $V$. Any help is much appreciated.
Edit: I feel like the following is true but not sure if it will help:

$\tag{3} W^\perp=((W^\perp)^\perp)^\perp$

To see it, recall $W\subseteq (W^\perp)^\perp$, since $\cdot^\perp$ is decreasing, we have $W^\perp \supseteq ((W^\perp)^\perp)^\perp$. For the converse, just replace $W$ by $W^\perp$ in the recall, that is, $W^\perp\subseteq ((W^\perp)^\perp)^\perp$.
By (3), I have (2) is true due to closedness in $V$, but again, this does not give info about proving (2) in a purely linear algebra way.

The only if part of (1) is not true in general, because $W=(W^\perp)^\perp$ is weaker than $W=\overline{W}$.
Here are some counter-examples to (1):

An example when $(U^\perp)^\perp = U$ but $V\ne U\oplus U^\perp$?

If $A$ and $A^\perp$ are closed then $A\oplus A^\perp=B$ for a Banach space $B$


Now, is (2) still always true?
